Pairs trading with 3+ assets
I am trying to understand how you would construct a pairs trading strategy on 3+ assets.
In the 2 asset case, assuming zero drift, we trade based on:
$$dX_t = \beta_AdS_t^A - \beta_B dS_t^B,$$
where $\beta_A=\frac{cov\left(S^A,S^B\right)}{\sigma^2_A}$, $\beta_B=\frac{cov\left(S^B,S^A\right)}{\sigma^2_B}$is the beta. But these betas' just become the ratio of the variances since their covariances are the same. Therefore, we effectively choose to short/long the ratio of their variances. So if $$\sigma^2_A = 0.20, \quad \sigma^2_B = 0.10$$
If stock A goes up $\\\$10$, then if we shorted $100$ shares of stock $A$, we would long $100\cdot\frac{0.20}{0.10}= 200$ shares of stock $B$.
If we decided to instead have 3 stocks $A, B, C$ and we have the correlation matrix:
$$
\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \rho_{A,B} & \rho_{A,C} \\
\rho_{B,A} & 1 & \rho_{B,C} \\
\rho_{C,A} & \rho_{C,B} & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
How could this be applied if we only traded 1 stock (let's choose $A$). (From here onwards, we assume the returns to have mean 0, $\mu=0$). In my contrived scenario, asset $A$ has the above correlation matrix, but the correlated returns movement is always delayed. In other words:
$$\text{corr}(dS^A_{t+1}, dS^B_{t}) = \rho_{A,B}$$
$$\text{corr}(dS^A_{t+1}, dS^C_{t}) = \rho_{A,C}$$
So we don’t need to long and short the pair since we have some certainty what A will be at time $t+1$ given the returns at $t$. We can just long/short $A$ depending on their returns and correlation of $B$ and $C$
In this case, what would the trade size amount be?
My initial intuition is that the size is equal to $$trade = \sum_{i=1}^{2}\text{movement} \times \text{correlation}\times \text{variance ratio}$$
So if $\sigma_B = \sigma_C$ and $\rho_{A,B} > \rho_{A,C}$, but then $dS^B_t=1$ and $dS^C_t=-1$ then we would buy $A$ in anticipation that it will rise since $A$ has a stronger correlation with $B$ (similarly if their correlations are equal, but 1 has higher volatility and or 1 has a larger movement).
This seems like a reasonable strategy given that we have this delayed correlation. The issue I run into with my logic is that if we have 4 assets instead. We can use the same logic as before:
$$trade = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\text{movement} \times \text{correlation}\times \text{variance ratio},$$ but the issue becomes what about the correlations between stocks $B,C,D$?
If $$\rho_{A,B} = 0.3$$ $$\rho_{A,C} = 0.3$$ $$ \rho_{A,D}=0.6$$
$$\sigma_A = \sigma_B = \sigma_C = \sigma_D$$ but $C$ and $D$ are highly correlated, like $\rho_{C,D} = 0.9$. Then in the scenario:
$$dS^B_t = -10$$
$$dS^C_t = 3$$
$$dS^D_t = 4$$
$D$ went up because it's highly correlated with $C$ (and vice-versa). Then we would have:
$$trade = -10 * 0.3 +  3 * 0.3 + 4 * 0.6$$ (ignoring the variance ratio since their vols are equal). To me, this doesn't seem reasonable because the movement from asset $D$ is kind of "baked into" asset $C$. So summing them would be kind of like double-counting?
How would I get around this?
I’m effectively asking: $$\mathbb{P}(dS^A_{t+1}> 0 | dS^B_t= -10, dS^C_t = 3,dS^D_t=4) $$
(If it’s bigger than $0.5$ we buy)
But I don’t think that’s possible since the events $\{dS^B_t= -10, dS^C_t = 3,dS^D_t=4\}$ aren’t measurable so conditioning on them isn’t possible.

I can't say anything about your approach but the multi-asset methodology I'm just slightly familiar with is taking the johansen approach to cointegration. This approach generalizes the 2 asset case ( the engle granger approach to cointegration ) to multiple assets. I have no idea if people use it successfully.  Johansen's's got books and papers and you are probably already familiar with it so I won't include references. I'm not suggesting to go this route. I'm just saying that its an approach that I know people have tried.

@markleeds I am not aware of this, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm after. In this contrived scenario, we observe the returns of stocks $B,C$ at time $t$ and we have the relationship for the returns of stock $A$ at time $t+1$, given by the correlation matrix. Therefore, at $t$ we observe the returns of $B,C$ and we immediately buy (sell) $A$. Then at $t+1$, $A$ adjusts according to the corr matrix, which use the returns of $B,C$ at $t$. Then at $t+1$, after the price observation, we sell (buy) for profit (on average because there is a correlation - ignoring fees).

@markleeds Here I am NOT looking at the reversion of the difference. There is an inherent lagged relation. It's kind of like an application of bayes, $\rho= \frac{(P(A\mid B)-P(A)) P(B)}{\sqrt{P(A)(1-P(A))P(B)(1-P(B))}}$. Here event A is the price of stock A going up at time $t+1$ and B is the event stock $B$ going up, which gives us probability of 0.65 (for $\rho=0.3$). If their vols are equal then the expected move of A becomes $E(dS^A_{t+1}) = 0.65*\sigma *dt$. But this taken to the 3+ stocks case and then we decide to buy/sell depending on the expected move from all the correlations.

Xerium: I'll print the full thread out and try to read it more carefully ( over the next day or two. I got a lot going on ) but don't count on me for any insights. The part about the lagging is unfamiliar to me but I'll read it all over again and see if I can follow what you're doing. Atleast now I know that you're not trying to capture spread reversion, I don't think.

Hi Xerium: This is not an answer but more like a long comment. Let me show how your 2 asset model is really just the engle-granger cointegrating regression model un-normalized. Once you follow that, then, for the 3 asset case, you can either go the way you originally described ( which I have not had a chance to go through ) or you can use Johansen's generalization which I was talking about earlier.
Take the case where you consider just 2 assets.
Your model is:
$$dX_t = \beta_AdS_t^A - \beta_B dS_t^B  ~~~(1) $$
But, suppose I change some of the notation. So, I let $dX_t$ be equal to $\epsilon_t$. Also, I re-define things so that  $$dS_t^{A} = log(S_t^{A})$$ and $$dS_t^{B} = log(S_t^{B})$$.
I then normalize the relation in (1) by setting  $\beta_A = 1$.
These changes above result in the following model:
$$log(S_{t}^{A}) = \beta_{B} \times log(S_{t}^{B}) + \epsilon_t   ~~~(2) $$
But note that (2) is just the engler-granger cointegrating regression model where the cointegrating vector is $(1, \beta_B)$ rather than $(\beta_A, \beta_B)$.
Also, we no longer have the nice symmetry in the covariance so now $\beta_{B} = \frac{cov\left(log(S_t^{A}),log(S_t^{B})\right)}{\sigma^2_{B}}$
So, the formulae are kind of the same as you had for your case, except that
$\sigma^2_{A} = 1$ now because stock A and stock B are  no longer viewed as
interchangeable. This is a drawback of the engle-granger cointegration approach in that the results can be dependent on which stock is chosen
to be the dependent variable. People have constructed ways of dealing with this that aren't worth getting into here.
My point is that you are pretty much doing un-normalized engle-granger cointegration but you didn't explain how you obtained the variances, $\sigma^2_{A}$ and $\sigma^2_{B}$.
In the regression formulation that I wrote, $\sigma^2_{B}$ comes directly from the regression of log prices of A on the log prices of $B$. Also, the residuals of the regression model need to be checked for stationarity. It's not clear to me how you obtain the variances without running a regression relation of some kind. Do you run total least squares possibly ?
ARBITRAGE IN THE 2 ASSET CASE
Note that, just because one arrives at the regression model, it's still not clear how one would do the arbitrage if the long term equilibrium relationship seems out of sync.
One way to about it is to write out the ECM implied by the cointegrating regression model:
Given (2), the corresponding  ECM model is shown below:
(See this for a heuristic derivation:  https://users.wfu.edu/cottrell/ecn215/misc/extra/error_corr_2008.pdf )
$$\Delta log(S_{t}^{A}) =\gamma_1 \times \Delta log(S_{t}^{B}) + \gamma_2 \times (log(S_{t}^{A}) -\beta _{B} \times log(S_{t}^{B})) + \nu _{t}$$
So, the steps become:

Estimate the model using Ordinary least squares:

$$log(S_{A}^{t}) = \beta \times log(S_{B}^{t}) +\epsilon _{t}$$

Check that the estimated residuals, $\hat{\epsilon_t}$ are stationary. If they are, then the estimated residuals ${\hat{\epsilon _{t}}=  log(S_{t}^{A}) - \beta _{B} \times log(S_{t}^{B}})$ from this regression are saved and used in the ECM representation.

$ \Delta log(S_{t}^{A}) = \gamma_1 \times \Delta log(S_{t}^{B})+ \gamma_{2}  \times \hat{\epsilon}_{t-1}+\eta _{t}$.


Now estimate (3) to find $\hat{\gamma_1}$ and $\hat{\gamma_2}$.
The ECM representation in Step 3)  is useful because, once you have $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, you then have a way of measuring when it looks like the true current spread ${\epsilon}_{t}$ is going to either A) revert from it's currently large value or widen due to its currently small value. Without the ECM representation, there is no easy way to really gauge the long term dis-equilibrium for an arbitrage possibility.

I get the variances from historical data. For example, during the overnight period of the futures close of the ICE futures, I take the historical variance from close to open (this is my $A$ that I’m trying to measure). Then I use multiple futures from the CBOE futures since they’re opened when ICE futures are closed. From the collection of moves of the futures, calculate their historical volatilities during that period as well as the correlation between their movement during ICE close and the ICE future price at $t+1$. I use the variances to remove the bias of the higher volatility futures.

In other words, I am trying to find the implied move at $t+1$ from the collection of moves during a previous time period. We obviously cannot trade this because the market will price in the overnight movement from geopolitical events and other exchanges moves, but I am trying to gauge what the implied move is at open nonetheless.

Sorry Xerium but what are $S_t^{A}$ and what $S_{t}^{B}$. $S_t^{A}$ I think are ICE futures. But what's $S_t^{B}$ ? Also, I'm gonna add something to my long comment about  arbing it in the two asset case. That's even not straightforward in my experience.

Xerium: I just added to the comment so that it's somewhat complete.  The comment provides a summary of a methodology for arbing the long term equilibrium relationship between two assets which are cointegrated. The ecm step is not always used. For example, one could take the estimated residuals and try to model them seperately as say an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process or an AR(1). This might be  viewed as a stretch but it's another possibility. I hope this all helps some. If you have the prices of both assets, it's something to try.

Oh, if you want to go to more than 2 assets, then you could read about Johansen's cointegration approach. It handles the case where the dimension of the cointegrating vector is greater than 2. It's mathematically more demanding than the EG approach. I'm sure there must be a plethora of examples on the internet.
